# How do I open maximized internet explorer?

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, shdocvw

I have to open maximized internet explorer using C#. I have tried the following:

```
try
{
    var IE = new SHDocVw.InternetExplorer();
    object URL = "http://localhost/client.html";

    IE.ToolBar = 0;
    IE.StatusBar = true;
    IE.MenuBar = true;
    IE.AddressBar = true;
    IE.Width = System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Width;
    IE.Height = System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Height;

    IE.Visible = true;

    IE.Navigate2(ref URL);
    ieOpened = true;

    break;
}
catch (Exception)
{

}
```

I can open with different sizes, but I couldn't find how to open maximized IE. I have checked the [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752084%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), there is no property to for maximize.

Please give me some suggestions.

PS: I am developing C# console application, .Net4.5, and VS2012

Comment: _Off topic:_ Why is there a `break` statement?

Comment: @Krumia on top of it there is while loop which checks for other dependenices to open the IE

Comment: Here's a hack: Maybe you can use [`TheaterMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752077(v=vs.85).aspx), and then set properties like `MenuBar` afterwards to get the desired output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use the process method.

1. You could start any executable and
2. It has a property which starts your process maximized

   ```
   ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("IExplore.exe");
   startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;
   startInfo.Arguments = "www.google.com";

   Process.Start(startInfo);
   ```

Answer (score 7):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Maximize_IE
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var IE = new SHDocVw.InternetExplorer();
            object URL = "http://google.com/";

            IE.ToolBar = 0;
            IE.StatusBar = true;
            IE.MenuBar = true;
            IE.AddressBar = true;

            IE.Visible = true;
            ShowWindow((IntPtr)IE.HWND, 3);
            IE.Navigate2(ref URL);
            //ieOpened = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Quick google of "csharp maximize SHDocVw window" gives this example:

```
[DllImport ("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hwnd, int nCmdShow);
private const int SW_MAXIMISE = 3;

public void OpenWindow()
{
       SHDocVw.InternetExplorer ie = new SHDocVw.InternetExplorer();  //Instantiate the class.
        ShowWindow((IntPtr)ie.HWND, SW_MAXIMISE);   //Maximise the window.
        ie.Visible = true;   //Set the window to visible.
}
```

Comment: replace SHDocVw.InternetExplorerClass() with SHDocVw.InternetExplorer() thanks

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
  var proc = new Process
            {
              StartInfo = {
                 UseShellExecute = true,
                 FileName = "http://localhost/client.html",
                 WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized
              }
            };
  proc.Start();
```