# Display IE in full screen mode but show taskbar

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, taskbar

I use C# to run IE browser by code

```
new InternetExplorer();
```

I want IE runs in full screen mode, and I also want the taskbar shows at the bottom of IE instead of covering the bottom.
Can someone tell me how to do?

Comment: check this- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25283517/how-do-i-open-maximized-internet-explorer

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way using Process.Start() with command line parameter 
-k :Starts Internet Explorer in kiosk mode

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("iexplore.exe"," -k http://google.com");
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13030414/open-a-page-in-ie-using-c-sharp